# Cannot read property 'id' of null ember

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ember.js, ember-data, wordpress-rest-api

I am attempting to fetch data from a WordPress application with an Ember application. I am attempting to fetch the menu item in WordPress with the ID of '2'. I am using the ember-wordpress plugin and can successfully get my posts, I am just struggling to grab the menu from the API.

Below is my menu model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  count: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Here is my route.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      menu: this.store.findRecord('menu', 2)
    });
  }

});
```

However when I try hit the URL I get the error in my console

> Error while processing route: Cannot read property 'id' of null
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Here is the JSON I am getting from my end point.

```
{
"ID": 2,
"name": "Main Menu",
"slug": "main-menu",
"description": "",
"count": 2,
"items": [
{
"id": 19,
"order": 1,
"parent": 0,
"title": "Projects",
"url": "http://localhost:8888/ember-wp/projects/",
"attr": "",
"target": "",
"classes": "",
"xfn": "",
"description": "",
"object_id": 17,
"object": "page",
"object_slug": "projects",
"type": "post_type",
"type_label": "Page"
},
{
"id": 20,
"order": 2,
"parent": 0,
"title": "Services",
"url": "http://localhost:8888/ember-wp/services/",
"attr": "",
"target": "",
"classes": "",
"xfn": "",
"description": "",
"object_id": 15,
"object": "page",
"object_slug": "services",
"type": "post_type",
"type_label": "Page"
}
],
"meta": {
"links": {
"collection": "http://localhost:8888/ember-wp/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/",
"self": "http://localhost:8888/ember-wp/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/2"
}
}
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're using the [WP API Menus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/) plugin to pull down data, as I ran into the same issue. You're going to need to edit one of the files in that plugin to correct this.

In `wp-api-menus-v2.php`…

1. On line 108, change `$rest_menus[ $i ]['ID'] = $menu['term_id'];` to `$rest_menus[ $i ]['id'] = $menu['term_id'];`
2. On line 143, change `$rest_menu['ID'] = abs( $menu['term_id'] );` to `$rest_menu['id'] = abs( $menu['term_id'] );`

Changing those two keys from uppercase to lowercase will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the error you get, but the first element does not have an 'id' field but an 'ID' field (uppercase).